# C#: How to get Firebase user jwt token without incoming request?

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, jwt, bearer-token

I want to write integration tests, so I need to attach Firebase jwt token to call api methods. 
I don't have any incoming requests, I want to get token by calling some Firebase api methods or by using some Firebase C# libraries. At the moment, I didn't find any proper libraries, there are some existing but they are outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was pretty simple.
Google provides api to [connect with email/password.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password)
*https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY]*

So, these worked pretty fine.

```
HttpResponseMessage response;
response = await client.PostAsync(FirebaseSignInUri, content);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   response = await client.PostAsync(FirebaseSignUpUri, content);
}
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var authResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthorizationResponse>(responseBody);
return authResponse;
```